# TypeError: ' Float object not Iterable'

Tags: python, min

I have  Datalog file in the format

```
41, 3.68, 3.58, 3.71, 3.54, 3.68, 3.79
42, 3.69, 3.57, 3.73, 3.55, 3.67, 3.78
43, 3.68, 3.57, 3.73, 3.54, 3.68, 3.79
44, 3.68, 3.57, 3.73, 3.54, 3.67, 3.79
45, 3.68, 3.57, 3.73, 3.54, 3.67, 3.78
46, 3.68, 3.57, 3.73, 3.54, 3.67, 3.78
47, 3.68, 3.57, 3.73, 3.54, 3.67, 3.78
48, 3.68, 3.57, 3.73, 3.54, 3.67, 3.78
49, 3.68, 3.57, 3.73, 3.54, 3.67, 3.78
```

For each column I am trying to find the minimum value and the corresponding row number.

But with the below code the `min()` function gives the 'float object not iterable error.

```
with open("Datalog.txt", "r") as file:
    result = [[float(x) for x in line.split(",")] for line in file]
    for i in range (len(result[0])):
        for j in range (len(result)):
            print (result[j][i])
            print (min(result[0][i]))
```

Comment: Please tag the language

Comment: I am new to Stackoverflow & it said i need min 1000 credits to start tagging python 3.5..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

min iterates through the list/tuple in the argument and gives you the smallest item in it, but you're providing it with a float, so it's trying to iterate through the float.

There's absolutely no reason to do this, but it's not gonna crash if you do:

```
print (min(result[0][i],))
```

since now it's not a float, but a tuple. It will just print the value of result[0][i]

If what you want is to get the minimum value in each line, you gotta do:

```
for i in range (len(result)):
    print (min(result[i]))
```

If what you want is the minimum in each column (assuming all rows have the same number of columns), you gotta do:

```
for j in range(len(result[0]))
    print ('minimum in column ' + str(j) + ':')
    print (min([result[i][j] for i in range(len(result))]))
```

where j is the index of the column

Comment: I am trying to get the minimum value of each column, the above code will give the min of each row.

Comment: @crank2giri try the one in the bottom that i edited now

Comment: TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer , looks like for "J in range(result[0]): " should be "J in result(0) :"

Comment: @crank2giri oops sorry. i think it's fixed

Comment: thanks a lot mate! got it. it works now. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is because in

```
print (min(result[0][i]))
```

`result[0][i]` is a single `float` object, not a list as you expected.

Instead, give a list to `min`:

```
for j in range (len(result)):
    print(result[j][0])
    print(min(result[j][1:]))
```

The range `[1:]` means everything except the first element.